# How can I assign a filename passed from command line in a C script?

Tags: c, bash

Given a command line tool which I use in the command line like this: `./tool img/file.png`

How can I assign the first argument to a variable? I tried `*argv[1]`, `&argv[1]`, `malloc(sizeof(argv[1]))` but then I get an `invalid initializer` error. Did I just not get a basic C concept or where am I stuck? Thanks for your help!

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    char block1_arg_Filename[] = "img/file.png"; //that's how it works but I don't need it

    char block1_arg_Filename[] = argv[1]; // don't get it to work but that's how I need it

    [...]

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: what is a "C script"?

Comment: @glglgl Correct me straight forwardly, if this is the purpsose of your question :)

Comment: & preferrably, don't use `char ** argv`. Use `char *argv[]`.

Comment: To the compiler, there's no difference between `char ** argv` and `char *argv[]`; though I do agree, the latter probably conveys intention somewhat better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* block1_arg_Filename = argv[1];
```

Of course, check `argc > 1` before trying this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but still the same error... some lines down I pass it to a function where a warning is displayed too: 'passing argument 1 of cvLoadImage from incompatible pointer type. I only get the "invalid initializer" error and no warning when using const char. I would be grateful for any further ideas :)

Comment: Argh... sorry, forgot to get rid of the "[]" Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First you should check that the argument exist, by checking `argc`. Then simply assign it to a `char *` if you can't use `argv[x]` directly (which you should be able to do).

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    if (argc > 1) {
      char *str = argv[1];
      /** do some stuff **/
    }

    return 0;

}
```

try this

Comment: If you try this `if` pattern with more than a couple arguments you gonna have a bad time.